# Import SQL with SSH

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux, ssh

I wanted to import a dump sql file via ssh like:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uUSER -pPASS DATABASE < dump.sql
```

But it actually overwrites and removes the old database. The dump is tagged with "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" but why does it remove the old entries? This dump was supposed to add NEW (unique) entries into the database but it removes old database entries.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: well of course "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" removes old entries, it removes the whole table

Comment: That's exactly what `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` does.  The table exists, so it is discarded before doing whatever `INSERT`s are in the file.  Remove the `DROP TABLE` if you don't want to lose what's there, and beware key violations when loading the records in the file.

Comment: thanks, I don't want to upload that SQL again, is there no way to use a command like (ignore DROP TABLE) in SSH to make it run?

Comment: why can't you edit your .sql file to remove the drop table statement?

Comment: I can, but it's pretty big. Than I have to reupload again.

Comment: reupload is not necessary if you edit it using vi or nano in you terminal: `nano dump.sql` (search with ctrl+W for DROP and remove those lines)

Answer (score 0):

There are various options you can pass to MySQLDump so that the script will only contain what you need (e.g. omit the create table statements and just insert data): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

I think you're interested in --no-create-info and --no-create-db in particular.

If you need to work with the dump you already have, just remove the offending "DROP TABLE" lines from it manually.

Comment: And if producing the table is beyond your control: grep -v 'DROP TABLE' dump.sql | mysql might work.

Comment: hm I get access denied with this command. unfortunately --no-create-info and --no-create-db does not work either. It's a FreeBSD system.

Answer (score 0):

> The dump is tagged with "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" but why does it remove the old entries?

That's exactly what `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` does; if the table is there, it gets dropped (removed) together with all the rows inside of it.

When creating the dump you could add `--skip-add-drop-table` option.